# How to update account address to contact address using triggers

Tags: trigger

```
trigger Updatechildrecord on Account(before insert, before update) {
   
    List<Contact> Conlist = new List<Contact> ();
    for(Contact c : [SELECT Name,Id,Phone From Contact Where AccountId IN: Trigger.New]) {
        for(Account acc : c) {
            c.MailingAddress = acc.BillingAddress;
            
            conlist.add(c);
            }
      Update conlist;
}
}
```

Am getting an error : Error: Compile Error: Field is not writeable: Contact.MailingAddress at line 6 column 15

Someone help me to clear this error. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address fields are not writable. You need to update different fields of an address as below:

```
Account a;
for(Contact c : [SELECT Name,Id,Phone From Contact Where AccountId IN: Trigger.New]) {
        a = Trigger.newMap.get(c.AccountId);
        c.MailingStreet     = a.BillingStreet;
        c.MailingCity       = a.BillingCity;
        c.MailingState      = a.BillingState;
        c.MailingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode;
        c.MailingCountry    = a.BillingCountry;
    }
    update contacts;
```

Refer this for compound fields -> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields_address.htm

Also, Make sure you are following Apex best practice to write your logic. Try to use a map instead of using for inside for loop. Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices for apex best practice.

Comment: Eventhough I changed ur code am getting an error.Error: Compile Error: Loop must iterate over collection: Contact at line 5 column 9

Comment: Yes, because In this block <for(Account acc : c) {>, you are trying to iterate over account but you are using c which is a contact. Please check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm to learn about loops.

Comment: Intsead we can create a new varaible for account acc : a like this and can try those?

Comment: Why are you using for inside for loop? I have updated my answer. You can check it

Comment: Thanks @Aakriti.G Its working

Comment: Can you please  mak this as answer & close the thread